# google play service has no folder in url

Tags: android, eclipse

im doing a log in via google app and the tutorial requires me to get the google play service but i cant find the folder in the url.i download it already as you can see in this printscreen [image] my problem is when i go to this url `<android-sdk>/extras/google/google_play_services/.` this is what i get [image]which means i cant access this url

```
android-sdk-windows\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib
```

and i cant proceed to the found [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/) any ideas about this issue?im stuck in this step `3. Importing Play Services Library to Eclipse`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this looks like you might have 2 SDK locations

have a look at this: [Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.59 3.2.25 4.0.30 4.1.32 4.2.40 4.2.42 4.3.23 4.4.52 5.0.77 5.0.89 5.2.08 6.1.11 6.1.71 6.5.87](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17155475/could-not-find-com-google-android-gmsplay-services3-1-36-3-2-25-4-0-30-4-2-40/17157227#17157227)

Comment: yea i have two sdk do i need to delete the other one?the other one is worse than this one google folder has nothing in it.i have all repository updated everything in sdk.the only thing i didnt update is the one that is not compatible with windows.by the way can i import it from another source

Comment: It doesn't matter if you have more than one sdk.The most important thing is to reference the right one after you perform an update or install.

Comment: yea - delete one of them to prevent future problems ( you might want to link both locations - but I am not sure how this is done with windows ) - and as this seems to be the right answer - please accept it ;-)

Comment: does it matter if i copied the google play form another source?because im getting error in @integer/google_play_services_version in the manifest file

Comment: what did you copy and what exactly is the error? Better open a new question for this as these comments get messy otherwise

Answer (score 0):

You can try downloading with another SDK manager to see if you get the same result.