# Android Studio Error using gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio, build.gradle

I'm using Android Studio with Gradle for my project. I had to convert it from eclipse to android studio. But I get this error

```
Failed to find: com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.77
```

That's my **build.gradle** file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.org.appname"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 17
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    // Google Play Services
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.77'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
    compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.3'
    compile 'io.segment.analytics.android:google-analytics:1.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.3'
}
```

What's Wrong? I have installed the Google Repository like a read in some other post. But it doesn't work.
Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17155475/could-not-find-com-google-android-gmsplay-services3-1-36-3-1-59-3-2-25-4-0-30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this line:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.+'
```

Instead of

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.77'
```

**Edit:**
This is a **bad** practice, please use exact version if possible and **avoid** using `+`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89`. You can find the available versions in `extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services` of your Android SDK directory.