# Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.77

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, google-play-services

I am facing this error while importing a gradle project to eclipse ADT.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':qodeme'.

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':qodeme:_defaultFlavorDebugCompile'.
  >   Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.77.
  >    Required by:
  >        QCodeMe-Android:qodeme:unspecified
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17155475/could-not-find-com-google-android-gmsplay-services3-1-59-3-2-25-4-0-30-4-1-32

You need to have Android Support Repository and Android Support Library installed in the Android SDK manager.also Google Repository and Google Play Service

Answer (score 6):

change to `com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89`

`5.0.77` is gone - had the same problem :-(

edit the build.gradle and replace the 77 by a 89

Comment: What is the proper way of doing it? Please explain.

Comment: That version appears to have been removed when I updated my sdk with the Android Sdk manager. I had the same problem and had to upgrade.

Comment: My build.gradle is empty. Any other solution?

Comment: I think it is just your root gradle that is empty - look for a filled one in the subdirectories

Comment: How to know exactly what version is installed in my sdk folder?

Comment: I found the versionName under the `<manifest>` tag of `<path-to-android-sdk>/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib/AndroidManifest.xml`