# Gradle can not find google play dependency

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, google-play-services

I try to repair the dependency to google play services in my android project. It already worked but now it is broken. I think this happened in between the Android Studio beta- and release-version.

This is the dependency in the build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
}
```

Android Studio was able to autocomplete the version string: '6.5.87' So I thought it knows how to solve the dependency. But it does not.. This is what I treid:

- reinstaled Android Studio (1.0.1) and the Android SDK
- used several play-service versions (incl. tried to use '+')
- tried to 'gradlew clean' the project
- installed almost everything from the Android SDK Manager. (incl. Google Repository and Android Support Repository)
- set all environment variables to the correct path

But I still get this error if I try to do a gradle project sync:

> Error:Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87.
>   Searched in the following locations:
>       file:/C:/Users/MyName/.m2/repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services/6.5.87/play-services-6.5.87.pom
>       file:/C:/Users/MaName/.m2/repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services/6.5.87/play-services-6.5.87.jar
>       https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services/6.5.87/play-services-6.5.87.pom
>       https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services/6.5.87/play-services-6.5.87.jar
>       https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/google/android/gms/play-services/6.5.87/play-services-6.5.87.pom
>       https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/google/android/gms/play-services/6.5.87/play-services-6.5.87.jar
>       https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/com/google/android/gms/play-services/6.5.87/play-services-6.5.87.pom
>       https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/com/google/android/gms/play-services/6.5.87/play-services-6.5.87.jar
>   Required by:
>       code:android:1.0

**UPDATE:**

Gradle is searching in "file:/C:/Users/MyName/.m2/repository/" but it should use 
"file:/C:/Users/MyName/AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\google\m2repository" .. I dont know why this is wrong and how to fix it..

**UPDATE 2**

I fixed it using this workaround:

```
repositories {
    def androidHome = System.getenv("ANDROID_HOME")
    maven { url "$androidHome/extras/android/m2repository/" }
    maven { url "$androidHome/extras/google/m2repository/"}
}
```

But I am not happy with it. Does anybody know whats wrong with my gradle?

Comment: This is odd because based on the error message it's not even looking in the SDK for the library, which it should -- it's in the sdk/extras/google/m2repository directory. I tried misconfiguring my project a few different ways and couldn't reproduce this situation, but you may want to double check that it knows where its SDK is.

Comment: Yes.. this is the error.. Do not know how to solve it :(

Comment: have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17155475/could-not-find-com-google-android-gmsplay-services3-1-59-3-2-25-4-0-30-4-1-32/17157227#17157227

Comment: I already read this post while investigation.. I dont have multiple  SDK's installed and "set all environment variables to the correct path"

Answer (score 15):

In Android SDK Manager download the "Google Repository"

Comment: i had same problem with  com.android.support:support , after install Android Support Repository worked as well..

Comment: This is the solution. The package can be found under the "Extras" subfolder at the bottom. you can launch the manager from the command line if you simply type `android`

Answer (score 2):

Try download the sdk and use this library

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
```

Answer (score 2):

After adding jcenter() to reposetories or top level gradle file I fixed the issue

```
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            mavenCentral()
        }

        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.1'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'
        }
    }
```