# Tried various solutions but still getting this Error:Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

This is the error I am getting. I tried everything and I am using android studio 1.3.1 version:

```
Error:Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0.
Required by:
    StockHawk-master:app:unspecified
<a href="searchInBuildFiles">Search in build.gradle files</a>
```

When I click the above link it finds the services but the gradle shows the error again and again.

Here is the build.gradle code :

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    apply plugin: 'android-apt'

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example..stockhawk"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-   rules.pro'
    }
  }
}

      repositories {
      maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
      }

      dependencies {
       compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
       compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
       apt 'net.simonvt.schematic:schematic-compiler:0.6.3'
       compile 'net.simonvt.schematic:schematic:0.6.3'
       compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.2.0'
       compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
       compile 'com.lsjwzh:materialloadingprogressbar:0.5.6-RELEASE'
       compile 'com.github.blackfizz:eazegraph:1.2.2@aar'
       compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
       compile('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.7@aar') {
       transitive = true
       }
      }
      apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17155475/could-not-find-com-google-android-gmsplay-services3-1-59-3-2-25-4-0-30-4-1-32