# TypeError: Cannot read property 'pushplugin' of undefined

Tags: nativescript

I installed this plugin via this command:
tns plugin add nativescript-push-notifications

I added the require statement to the top of my login.js
var pushPlugin = require("nativescript-push-notifications");

When I start the app I get this error:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.nativescript.myapp/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}: com.tns.NativeScriptException: 
Calling js method onCreate failed

Error calling module function

Error calling module function

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'pushplugin' of undefined
```

File: "/data/data/org.nativescript.myapp/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-push-notifications/push-plugin.js, line: 8, column: 19

```
StackTrace: 
Frame: function:'', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.myapp/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-push-notifications/push-plugin.js', line: 8, column: 20
Frame: function:'', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.myapp/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-push-notifications/push-plugin.js', line: 9, column: 7
Frame: function:'', file:'/data/data/org.nativescript.myapp/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-push-notifications/push-plugin.js', line: 51, column: 3
Frame: function:'require', file:'', line: 1, column: 266
Frame: fu`
```

My tns --version is 2.3.0

EDIT:  I created another project with tns create sample1
and added the plugin using tns plugin add like above and then added the code to the main-vew-model.js.  Here is the [code](https://jsbin.com/doxakagipo/edit?html,js,output).

**RESOLUTION:**

After installing the plugin I was running this command:

tns livesync android --watch

This evening after a few hours away I realized I should have been running:

tns run android

When I ran that I received this error:

> Could not find any matches for com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+ as no versions of com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm are available.

A search of that lead me to a StackOverflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17155475/could-not-find-com-google-android-gmsplay-services3-1-59-3-2-25-4-0-30-4-1-32) which showed me what I needed to do to get rid of that error.

After I installed the "Google Repository" in the SDK manager everything was A OK.

Comment: I have tested it on my side and I am not throwing error when calling pushPlugin.register()  ... now one thing I notice is that you have different casing in your description (pushPlugin vs pushplugin)  .. you can also try to update to the lastest NativeScript version (as of today it is  2.3.0)

Comment: I upgraded and same error.  The only code i put in so far is the require statement.  Could that be why it is throwing an error?  I haven't put in the code yet to do the Register.

Comment: It turns out that I needed to have it inside a function and not at the top of the JS file.  Once I did that the error went away.

Comment: Actually moving it to the function just postponed the error till I clicked the button that enters the function.