# "Ionic build android failure" after install push notifications

Tags: android, ionic-framework, push-notification, cloud

After installing the ionic push notifications (https://docs.ionic.io/services/push/), not a project is built, the code of the console:

http://pastebin.com/1rbmv0EW

please tell me what the problem is and how to solve it

`ionic -v`: **2.1.0-beta.3**
`npm -v`: **2.15.5**
`cordova -v`: **6.4.0**

Comment: Paste your example here please.

Comment: what kind of example do you want?

Comment: I meant you should copy and paste code (console commands) and output right here.

Comment: I solved the problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17155475/could-not-find-com-google-android-gmsplay-services3-1-59-3-2-25-4-0-30-4-1-32#